# Anyone getting "Last Logout" correct on openfire console for iOS?

Tags: ios, openfire, xmppframework

I am using https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework and tried to implement XMPPLastActivity to achieve XEP-0012. Everything is implemented successfully but the time received is wrong as "Last Logout" is not updated on my disconnection with openfire. Its working fine and accurate with android.

Comment: Did you get any success in getting this ?

Comment: Please check whether xmppCapabilities is properly integrated or not. I am not sure but it should work in that way.

Comment: There is no need of xmppCapabilities, I have implemented last seen (jabber:iq:last) and it returns me some value too, but that is not correct, even if user come online, it is not changed to 0. Sometimes I get -1 as well.

Comment: Yes I was facing the same issue.I went to openfire community and there someone answered me like this. Unfortunately I didn't get chance to verify.

Comment: Capabilities just add versions :|